# Mysql - how get unique dd-mm-YY from table?

Tags: mysql

Structure table:

```
date                   text
2014-11-01 12:23   test words
2014-11-01 12:23   test words
2014-11-02 12:23   test words
2014-11-01 12:23   test words
2014-11-03 12:23   test words
2014-11-01 12:23   test words
2014-11-04 12:23   test words
2014-11-04 12:23   test words
2014-11-07 12:23   test words



SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP by date
```

*but this query not getunique date in format dd-mm-YY...*

***Tell me please how get unique date dd-mm-YY from this table ?***

*P.S.: result should been next:*

```
2014-11-07
2014-11-04
2014-11-03
2014-11-02
2014-11-01
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `distinct`

```
SELECT distinct DATE(date) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

****Try using `distinct` and `date_format` ****

### **Table:-**

```
 user_id    email           db_add_date
   1        l@gmail.com 2014-05-14 03:09:17
   2        a@gmail.com 2014-05-21 08:21:00 
   3        b@gmail.com 2014-05-21 08:21:00
   4        c@gmail.com 2014-05-21 08:21:00
```

### Query:-

```
    SELECT 
       DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(db_add_date,'%d-%m-%Y') AS date 
       FROM table
```

### **Result:-**

```
  date
  14-05-2014
  21-05-2014
```